# How can my app (iOS) open a location from Google Maps' Share button?

Tags: ios, google-maps

Using the Google Maps app on iOS, when I tap the share button it will show me a list of apps to open that location with.

My question is, how do I get my app to be in that list? I'm guessing a custom URL scheme, but then, what is that scheme?

I'd like to be able to import a location into my app relatively easily for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a App Share Extension
[App Extension Programming Guide Share Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Not sure about that. For example, if I want my app to be able to open a .pdf, I have to register my app to be an editor of that url type. And then it would appear in the list of apps that can open that (location) when in GoogleMaps.  So the question is what url types should my app handle?

Comment: Yes, in fact this is the way to do it and I'm proceeding there.  Thanks for the tips!  As much as that link is somewhat helpful, the whole process wasn't entirely straightforward, and I ran into a snag when not paying attention to the deployment target of the extension.  I had to make sure an earlier version of iOS was supported that my device is running.  Then the standard Extension template in Xcode would theoretically work.  Thanks!